# i want to get only 3 blog of per category. but code return me all blogs of per category laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

**i want to get only 3 blog of per category. but code return me all blogs of per category laravel**

example i have 2 category (category 1 haves 10 blogs and category 2 haves 7 blog). now i want only 3 records of category 1 and 3 records of category 2 from DB

*my controller code.*

```
$categories = Category::has('blogs')->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: Category::has('blogs', function($q){ $q->take(3); } )->take(10)->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Category::with('blogs')->get()->map(function($category) {
    $category->setRelation('blogs', $category->blogs->take(3));
    return $category;
});
```

Should do your work

Comment: Glad to help you)

Comment: and how i can do this with single  "" Category::find(2);  ""

Comment: map() not working on. it see my code                                                                                                                                                   $categories = Category::find($this->catId)->load('blogs')->map(function($category) {
            $category->setRelation('blogs', $category->blogs->take(3));
            return $category;
        });

Comment: you have to ask new question to get new answer.